# Google App Engine request returns status code 200 when i'm expecting 403

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm making an android app that makes a request to a google app engine service. The service requires authentication with a google account.

I can authenticate the user and make a request with no problems. But i don't want to authenticate before every request, I'd rather check if it fails on authentication first.

I make the request like this:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString));
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
switch(statusCode)
{
    case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
    {
        //handle result
        break;
    }
    case HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN:
    {
    //handle authentication and request again
        break;
    }
}
```

The status code I always get back is 200 (HttpStatus.SC_OK). If I read the content in the response it's the default app engine Account Login page. Is there something i'm missing here? Why do i get status code 200 instead of a 403?

Comment: I haven't used it but are you sure you want to use HTTP without the _S_ for authentication with Google accounts? Maybe it's redirecting you because that would be too insecure? Or do they allow users to send Google account data unencrypted?

Comment: Ah, that might be it. I can't at the moment but when i get back i'll try it.

Comment: You should post some of your App Engine code. I'm guessing your problem actually has little to do with your Android code.

Comment: It's not my service, so I don't have the code for it.